# Admob Ads Revenue impact - How does revenue impact by having Single Activity or Multiple Activities in application?

Tags: admob, firebase-admob

Can someone help me to understant the Admob Ads Revenue impact by having Single Activity or Multiple Activities in application.

- Suppose in my App i have 5 different screens.
- **Case: A - Multiple Activities for each screen -** I'm showing banner app on each screen(that means i am loading ads and showing ads on each screen whenever user will navigate on pages within the app).
- **Case: B - Single Activity using fragments for each screen** - If i make this app using fragments with single Activity than i will be loading ads and showing ads only in one time when user will launch the app. After that it will display continuously.
- If we consider above case for same time. Than only difference will be the request call and showing Ads.

Here is the difference:

- In case A - Many request to show ads on each screen **(**not sure it result in multiple ads impressions)**.
- In case B - Single request to show ads in app ***(single ads impression)***.

I'm not sure how it will impact the revenue. Can someone clear my doubts so i can choose best approach for my app.

--Thanks in advance.